# Pinacol pinacolone rearrangement

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, stereochemistry, alcohols

I was reading the topic alcohol in that I saw a reaction Pinacol pinacolone rearrangement .

But I am not able to find the sterochemistry of the reaction .

Can anyone please tell me the stereochemistry [image]

Comment: In that example, there is no stereocentre.

Comment: see this:-http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/43858/why-do-we-have-an-alkyl-shift-rather-than-epoxidation-in-a-pinacol-reaction/43859#43859

Comment: @Martin-マーチン if there is a stereocentre in any other example then what would be the stereochemistry

Comment: @NilayGhosh in that question about stereochemistry is not mentioned .

Comment: This is perhaps the best explanation available- https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/64459/ring-contraction-in-pinacol-rearrangement-of-cyclohexane-1-2-diol

Answer (score 1):

The migrating group attacks trans to the leaving OH group:[image: pinacol rearrangement stereochemistry]

Comment: This answer implies a concerted mechanism, while the mechanism is usually written stepwise. Can you point us to papers that investigated the mechanism and came to this conclusion? As it stands, your answer seems claiming something without proving it.

Comment: Why in second mechanism it becomes five membered ring ?